# Grails: Utility class for tests that needs handle to grailsApplication.config

Tags: grails

I have a bunch of integration tests.  I want a class that has some utility methods that the tests use.  I started off making the utility methods all static and it was easy to get a handle to them from the tests.

However, I needed the utility class to be able to get a handle on the grailsApplication.confg so I could pull in some config.  To do this, because the utility class is not a service, I made the class implement `ApplicationContextAware`.  This meant I had to make the static methods instance based.  Fair enough.

To make it ApplicationContextAware, I implement interface and I do:

```
class TestUtils {
    def grailsApplication
    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext)
        throws BeansException {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          this.grailsApplication = grailsApplication
    }
    ...
```

But this never gets called meaning my local grailApplication ref is never set.

Is it better if I just made this TestUtility field a service or what are my doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can keep your utility class with static methods and access `grailsApplication` through the [Holders](http://grails.org/doc/latest/api/grails/util/Holders.html) class:

```
def grailsApplication = Holders.grailsApplication
```